# Android Volley : javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: (API URL changed from http to https)

Tags: java, android, sslhandshakeexception

When I am debugging my App using (*previously it was **http** ,now **https***) **"https://ims.domain_name.com/api/**". Every time I am getting below exception:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
```

When I used below piece of code, its working properly but once I updated my app on **Google Play Store** my app was rejected by play store saying:

> Hello Google Play Developer,
>
> We rejected My AppName , with package name com.domainName.ims, for
>   violating our Malicious Behavior  or User Data policy. If you
>   submitted an update, the previous version of your app is still
>   available on  Google Play.
>
> This app uses software that contains security vulnerabilities for
>   users or allows the collection of user  data without proper
>   disclosure.
>
> Below is the list of issues and the corresponding APK versions that
>   were detected in your recent submission. Please upgrade your app(s) as
>   soon as possible and increment the version number of the upgraded APK.

**Here is the code :**

```
/**
 * Enables https connections
 */
@SuppressLint("TrulyRandom")
public static void handleSSLHandshake() {
    try {
        TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[]{new X509TrustManager() {
            public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                return new X509Certificate[0];
            }

            @Override
            public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
            }

            @Override
            public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
            }
        }};

        SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
        sc.init(null, trustAllCerts, new SecureRandom());
        HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());
        HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() {
            @Override
            public boolean verify(String arg0, SSLSession arg1) {
                return true;
            }
        });
    } catch (Exception ignored) {
    }
}
```

Then, I deep search over the internet I got idea about it that I need to include my `.crt` file inside my app i.e, public key . But I didn't get the proper solution for this.

Now I have **SSL key** of my server i.e, `.crt` file.